# RUN time error 1004 , no data was selected to parse

Tags: excel, vba

i will have SVG  files in folder , i have written vba code to get XML data from SVG files here is the code

```
Sub Macro4()

Dim lines As Long
Dim letter As String
Dim no As String
Dim count As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim xRow As Long
Dim xDirect$, xFname$, InitialFoldr$

    count = Sheets.count
    If count > 1 Then
    For i = 1 To Sheets.count
        Sheets(i).Select
        On Error GoTo loopexit
        If ActiveSheet.Name = "Execute" Then
        ElseIf ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet1" Then
        Else
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            ActiveSheet.Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            i = i - 1
        End If
    Next i
    End If
loopexit:
    InitialFoldr$ = "C:\"
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\"
        .Title = "Please select a folder to list Files from"
        .InitialFileName = InitialFoldr$
        .Show
            If .SelectedItems.count <> 0 Then
                xDirect$ = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
                xFname$ = Dir(xDirect$, 7)
                Cells(1, 1).Select
                    Do While xFname$ <> ""
                       Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                       With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
                            "TEXT;" & xDirect$ & xFname$, Destination:=Range( _
                            "$A$1"))
                        .Name = Replace(xFname$, ".svg", "")
                        .FieldNames = True
                        .RowNumbers = False
                        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
                        .PreserveFormatting = True
                        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
                        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
                        .SavePassword = False
                        .SaveData = True
                        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
                        .RefreshPeriod = 0
                        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
                        .TextFilePlatform = 932
                        .TextFileStartRow = 1
                        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
                        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
                        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
                        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
                        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
                        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
                        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
                        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1)
                        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
                        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
                        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                    End With
                    Rows("1:1").Select
                    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
                    lines = ActiveSheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
                    Rows("1:1").Select
                    Selection.AutoFilter
                    Range("A1").Select
                    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
                        "<>*text transform*", Operator:=xlAnd
                    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$I$" & lines).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells _
                        (xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
                    Range("A1").Select
                    Selection.AutoFilter
                    Range("A2").Select
                    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
                    Columns("A:A").Select
                    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
                        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
                        :=">", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1)), _
                        TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

i am getting **run time error 1004** , so i decided to execute line by line in the code 
i am applying filter to filter data "text transform" and remaining data i will delete , so in the code

```
 Rows("1:1").Select
                    Selection.AutoFilter
                    Range("A1").Select
                    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
                        "<>*text transform*", Operator:=xlAnd
                    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$I$" & lines).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells _
                        (xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
```

it will delete all data's except "text transform" data but when i execute this filter deletes all the datas what i get in **XML file**  so it shows error on the line  as **no data was selected to parse**

```
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
                        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
                        :=">", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1)), _
                        TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

why this error happens can anybody help me to rectify it?

Comment: please rectify this problem

Comment: why this error happens ?

Comment: please anybody help me in this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Not Range("C:C").Find("*") Is Nothing Then  'if it's not nothing then column contains data

'run your code

Else

'don't run your code - do something else eg warn user?

End If

check the link :  https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/447678-runtime-error-1004-no-data-selected-parse.html